# Audio record issue in windows phone 8.1 silver light application

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1

Hi i need to record audio using Micro Phone.I followed below link for implemented this. I am using Visual studio 2015 preview. In the project  capabilities its not showing videosLibrary
 . So because of this restriction, it is throwing following exception.

> Failed to capture audioSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is
>   denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))    at
>   Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.get_VideosLibrary()    at
>   EMM.AttachmentsUserControl.d__1.MoveNext()

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/837500/Recording-Audio-in-Windows-Phone

How to resolve this issue. Could any advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched  videosLibrary  in WMAppManifest file instead of Package.appxmanifest.This resolves my issue.